# thymeleaf date format while each

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I'm trying  to apply dates.format while I do a forEach in thymeleaf. But I get this message

> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception
>   evaluating OGNL expression: "e.datesCoordinates.created" (template:
>   "templates/alarms" - line 262, col 48)

If I do it outside an "th:each" It works perfectly. How can I make it work?

```
<div class="content" th:each="e : ${events}">
                            <div class="info date" th:value="${e.datesCoordinates.created}? ${#dates.format(e.datesCoordinates.created, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm')}"></div>
                            <div class="info operator" th:text="|${e.owner.first_name} ${e.owner.last_name}|"></div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: What type object are we dealing with `e.datesCoordinates.created`? Is it a String or some Date type?

Comment: it's a string ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since e.datesCoordinates.created is a String, you would need to parse it first, and then, you can format it. The following code should work.

```
<th:block th:with="sdf = ${new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm')}">      
    <div class="content" th:each="e : ${events}">
        <div class="info date" th:value="${e.datesCoordinates.created}? ${#dates.format(sdf.parse(e.datesCoordinates.created), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm')}"></div>
        <div class="info operator" th:text="|${e.owner.first_name} ${e.owner.last_name}|"></div>
    </div>
</th:block>
```

**Important**

When using `new java.text.SimpleDateFormat` you need to match the expression just like the current string format. For example, if you are saving like *10-03-2018*, then your code would look like this `${new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy')}`.